Should I (and how should I) align the types hints my abstract class and concrete class in Python?
I'm having an abstract class in Python like this
class Sinker(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def batch_write(self, data) -> None:
        pass

The concrete class is expected to write data to some cloud databases. My intention of writing abstract class this way was to make sure the concrete classes always implement the batch_write() method.
However, I'm not sure what type hints I should put in for data because one of my concrete class is expecting List[str] while another concrete class is expecting List[dict].
Here are just some options popped up in my head so far.

Any
List[Any]
List[str|dict]

What would be a better way to do so? Is there a style guide for this situation?
I tried out all three options and since they're just type hints, it won't cause me any trouble. But I just want to make sure I'm writing codes that are aligned with corresponding best practices in OOP if there's any.

For this kind of situation, your choice depends on what level of abstraction you want for you Abstract Base Class. If you know for sure that your argument will be a list the List[Any] seems the more suited. you first and third options being either too vague or specific.
Also don't forget the self in def batch_write(self, data), or declare it as a staticmethod.
Finally, even though I answered it, your question is not particularly a "problem", but more of a tip asking, so consider taking a look at the How to Ask

Thanks for the reminder! I've fixed the method and will take a look at the shared link.

You can make Sinker a generic class so the type of items in the list passed to batch_write can be parameterized:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Sinker[T](ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def batch_write(self, data: list[T]) -> None:
        ...

class StrSinker(Sinker[str]):
    def batch_write(self, data: list[str]) -> None:
        pass

class DictSinker(Sinker[dict]):
    def batch_write(self, data: list[dict]) -> None:
        pass

Demo with Pyright
This way, the type checker would be able to spot an incorrect type hint for you. For example, with:
class StrSinker(Sinker[str]):
    def batch_write(self, data: list[int]) -> None:
        pass

Pyright would produce the following complaint:
Method "batch_write" overrides class "Sinker" in an incompatible manner
  Parameter 2 type mismatch: base parameter is type "list[str]", override parameter is type "list[int]"
    "list[str]" is incompatible with "list[int]"
      Type parameter "_T@list" is invariant, but "str" is not the same as "int"
      Consider switching from "list" to "Sequence" which is covariant  (reportIncompatibleMethodOverride)

Demo with Pyright

Since the batch_write method is not commonly defined between all the Sinker instances, defining it ambiguously (Any or generic) on the Sinker won't add any clarity about how it should be used.
People will still need to look at the subclasses to determine if their arguments are acceptable. Therefore I don't think defining it on Sinker adds anything.
Instead wait until the subclass where the method (including its arguments) is fully defined before making the abstractmethod, even if this involves adding another abstract intermediate eg.
class SinkerStringBatchWritable(Sinker):
    @abstractmethod
    def batch_write(self, data: list[str]) -> None:
        pass


I would say Any is the recommended solution here. Since it is an abstractmethod, people cannot directly use/implement the batch_write method from Sinker, and it has pass statement, so in my opinion you don't need to be very specific. I would implement the more specific type hints in the batch_write method in the classes that inherit from Sinker.
Also, if you use List[dict | str] as type hint, then you are forced to update this type hint every time you implement a new child class which has a batch_write method where data has a different type (e.g. List[int]). Just be as generic as possible in the abstract class to avoid changing the signature. But, in case you are sure it will always be a list, you may choose for List[Any]`. (See command under your question from Lrx, I liked that one).

"cannot directly use/implement the batch_write method from Sinker"—Well you can call it on a Sinker object without necessarily knowing which concrete subclass is being used. That is the whole point of an abstract method. And the whole point of a return type hint is that you know what you will get back when you do that.

Ok, but the question is not about the return type, and the abstractmethod here is clearly meant to be specified in child classes. Maybe I should have written it as "you cannot instantiate the Abstractclass". That would have been better probably, but still, the abstractmethod doesn't do anything in this example. It would have made a huge difference if there was some actual logic in it. But then, I would also have suggested to use more specific type hints for the arguments.

I should have said "the point of a parameter type hint is to indicate what kind of argument is expected when you do that". Re "the abstractmethod here is clearly meant to be specified in child classes"-- All abstract methods are expected to be implemented in subclasses: that is what an abstract method is.

Thank you! I like the point that List[dict | str] might force me to change the abstract class whenever a new concrete class is implemented. I'm more confident to remove the third option.
